# Excute SQL script step by step with a pause

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way on SSMS or T-SQL to load a script on SSMS then press F5

Then SSSMS excute command by command script (what I mean, SSMS wait until a command is finish before starting an other one)

Then put a break somewhere. Then you have to press a button then the same script continues to be execute?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for the debugger and breakpoints

Comment: not really what I want it's to automatize a script.
Actually I do some truncate, inserts, updates, but i do it manually step by sstep. 
What i want is to launch the script press F5 then wait it's finish
then have a break to retrieve the informations control everything is ok 
then press a button to make my scripts continues until the end

Comment: The debug feature was removed from SSMS in SSMS 17 or 18 (I forget which). The feature is in SSDT though.

Comment: It sounds like you want to treat SQL like a programming language, @KeusT ; don't forget it *isn't* one.

Comment: Imagines my script has 100 steps. I want to set execute step 1 then step 2 then 3 etc. until step 24 
Then ask "press Y to continue" Then I press Y and the script continues to 25 to 45 (step by step).
Then ask "press Y to continue"  Then I press Y and my script goes 46 to 100

Comment: That sounds like a *programming* solution, @KeusT . Again, SQL isn't a programming language. SQL (Structured Query Language) is (as its name suggests) is a Query language.

Comment: Yeah that's mean I can't neither call a script with some parameter like a method in programming language?

Comment: Might be a good usecase for jupyter notebook's ipython-sql module with pyodbc. You could toss your blocks of sql into their own notebook cells and then run through it step by step. [a good walk through of this functionality here](https://towardsdatascience.com/heres-how-to-run-sql-in-jupyter-notebooks-f26eb90f3259).

Comment: [Step Through Transact-SQL Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/step-through-transact-sql-code?view=sql-server-ver16) using  [Transact-SQL debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/transact-sql-debugger?view=sql-server-ver16) ?